# Set all outgoing network traffic to go through a certain proxy

Tags: c#, .net, c++, qt

I think I know how to do this in windows with registry entry.  Any cleaner ways with .NET?

Anyway to do this in Qt, so for Macs as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such way on Windows. For starters, the most common way to do so only works for outgoing **HTTP** traffic. FTP, NNTP, or Doom 2 will not be affected. Secondly, most webbrowsers **copy** the proxy information from WinInet/Internet Explorer (which you happen to assume is in the registry). Changing the original doesn't update those copies. Furthermore, quite often in companies the proxy will depend on the destination (google "proxy.pac" for details)

Answer (score 0):

If you want that all data of one pc goes through a specific proxy, this can't be done in software on the same machine (or more precise: within the same OS instance). If you need such a thing you need a second (virtual) machine where you enter the ip address of this second pc as gateway for the first one. Now all ip traffic from the first one is forwarded to the second one and this has now to decide what should happen with these packets. That's the way how routers and firewalls are working.